# What all do to use Log stash to publish often changing different .log files from UNIX machines?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I could in url https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html that Log stash requires java 8.Does it mean log stash not supports all java versions < java 8 ?.
Please let me know overall steps
How to show often changing different .log files from different UNIX machines in KIBANA in more graphical way using Log stash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_jvm:
Logstash 5+ does not support versions earlier than 8. Older versions of Logstash (up to 2.4) supports java 7.

Comment: Thank you can we use Log-stash 2.4 rather using log stash 5.Is there any major change in Log-stash 5 ?

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming I have no idea of what's new in LS 5. We are still using 1.5 in production after finding that LS 2+ has problems with our architecture. The release notes are [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/releasenotes.html) and you have some info [there](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-5-0-0-released)